# What is the value of a string?

Tags: java, string

If I were to create a String in Java:

```
String example = "text";
```

what is the value of the variable example?  At first I said that the value is: text, with no quotes, but now I am second guessing myself thinking that the value is: "text", with quotes.  Help!

Comment: The value of `"text"` is the string `"text"`, without quotes. To get `"text"` with quotes, use `"\"text\""`

Comment: Create an example, debug it and you'll see many information about this variable.. including its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable value is `text` with no quotes. The quotes are only here to specify that the provided data is a string and not a variable name.

If you want to store `"text"` in a variable, you'll have to do :

```
string s = "\"text\"";
```

To be technically accurate, as Henry pointed out below, the actual value of the variable is a memory reference to a `String` instance containing `text`.

Comment: Actually the value is a reference to a String instance with the value `text` without quotes.

Comment: Technically you're right of course, but I'm not sure that it's what the OP asked :)

Comment: I see.  Thank you. Although I'm not sure why this was down-voted so much haha.  I thought people loved easy questions ...

Comment: @X.L.Ant It may not be what the OP **intended** to ask for. However, technically, it is exactly what the OP asked for. :)

Comment: @Alderath : True. That's why I edited my answer to specify this.

Answer (score 1):

The value is `text` without quotes.
you can use systemout to print the value of a String to the console to simply test it:

```
String example = "text";
System.out.println(example);
```

Result:

`text`